# Binary search to solve 'Kth Smallest Element in a Sorted Matrix'. How can one ensure the correctness of the algorithm,

Tags: binary-search, whiteboard

I'm referring to the leetcode question: [Kth Smallest Element in a Sorted Matrix](https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-smallest-element-in-a-sorted-matrix/description/)

There are two well-known solutions to the problem. One using Heap/PriorityQueue and other is using Binary Search. The Binary Search solution goes like this ([top post](https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-smallest-element-in-a-sorted-matrix/discuss/85173/Share-my-thoughts-and-Clean-Java-Code)):

```
public class Solution {
public int kthSmallest(int[][] matrix, int k) {
    int lo = matrix[0][0], hi = matrix[matrix.length - 1][matrix[0].length - 1] + 1;//[lo, hi)
    while(lo < hi) {
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        int count = 0,  j = matrix[0].length - 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            while(j >= 0 && matrix[i][j] > mid) j--;
            count += (j + 1);
        }
        if(count < k) lo = mid + 1;
        else hi = mid;
    }
    return lo;
}
}
```

While I understand how this works, I have trouble figuring out one issue.
How can we be sure that the returned `lo` is always in the matrix?

Since the search space is `min` and `max` value of the array, the `mid` need NOT be a value that is in the array. However, the returned `lo` always is.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of argument, we can move the calculation of `count` to a separate function like the following:

```
bool valid(int mid, int[][] matrix, int k) {
    int count = 0, m = matrix.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < m && matrix[i][j] <= mid) j++;
        count += j;
    }
    return (count < k);
}
```

This predicate will do exactly same as your specified operation. Here, the loop invariant is that, the range `[lo, hi]` always contains the `kth` smallest number of the 2D array.

In other words, `lo <= solution <= hi`

Now, when the loop terminates, it is evident that `lo >= hi`

Merging those two properties, we get, `lo = solution = hi`, since `solution` is a member of array, it can be said that, `lo` is always in the array after loop termination and will rightly point to the `kth` smallest element.

Comment: This is where I'm confused. Why is `solution` always in the array? If my range is [0,1,2,3,4,5,.....n-2,n-1,n] of [[0,1],[n-1,n]] matrix, the `mid` can be any number from [0,n] in between loops.

However when low>=hi and the loop terminates, why does the low and mid have to be between [0,1,n-1,n].

Comment: @ Snehasis Ghosh The solution variable is defined as the result of this problem

Answer (score 0):

Because We are finding the lower_bound using binary search and there cannot be any number smaller than the number(lo) in the array which could be the kth smallest element.